# How to select a name that the cat will learn quickly and enjoy hearing?

Tags: cats, pet-names

Cats' hearing is fundamentally different from humans'. What makes for a name that a cat would easily recognize? Specific sounds? Combinations? Rhythm? Length?

Comment: https://www.thesprucepets.com/how-to-name-your-cat-4773711

Comment: I think this should stay open. It is about how to live well with a cat (by naming it with a name, the cat can remember, notice and do not mix with other sounds). It is not searching for the most beautiful name or similar.

Comment: Agree that this should stay open, possibly related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18462/should-cats-be-given-names-which-end-with-a-vowel?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, names over 2 syllables are harder to remember, and sounds more or less close to what a cat can produce are easier to remember. Other than that, try out a list of names and see how your cat reacts to each one. If the cat has some kind of a positive reaction to a name you say (turns to it, looks interested, etc.), try it a few more times to see if the reaction persists or is just a fluke.
That said, cats are intelligent enough to get used to anything you call them eventually, so if you think some name fits your cat particularly well and the cat doesn't have a visceral negative reaction to the sound of it, it will work in the end.

Answer (score 0):

My mother adopted a dog many years ago. She did not know how to call it. So she called him names, until the dog reacted. That name remained.

So just do the same. No two cats (or people, or dogs, or whatever) are the same. Call your cat names, until he / she reacts in the way you want. Settle for that name. After that, just be happy with your new pet friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether my cat recognizes her name; she seems more to react to tone of voice. Which means that I wind up with a cat in my lap almost every time I'm talking to a friend on the phone.

If I really want her to come, I whistle.